# how to clear text box inside a macro?

Tags: ms-access

I have a macro for onclick event for a combo, how do i have something to clear the text box in the same form when the user click on combo box and make selection. I would like to do the clear inside the same macro rather than a procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Not clear what you mean by macro? Do you mean the new macro language in Access, or do you mean VBA code?

In VBA code you can just go:

```
Me.MyComboBox = null
```

In macro code, you use [SetProperty](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SetProperty-Macro-Action-a8ecea05-afbb-4234-a007-42dd131a2559?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), input the name of your Control, set the Property to "Value" and just leave the Value blank.

[image]