# Clear Textbox on key press

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Is there any way to clear the textbox on keypress like in excel.

I tried the following code but it clears the text when clicking on the textbox. I want it to clear it when a certain key is pressed.

```
Private Sub Text10_GotFocus()
Text10.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to clear text box inside a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588096/how-to-clear-text-box-inside-a-macro)

Comment: The functionality should be like excel. In excel you type in a number and then click somewhere else. When you click in the same textbox again and press a key it gets erased. I want to implement the same functionalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select the control's entire text content whenever that control gets focus.  Then your keypress would replace the selected text.

If you want that to happen for every text box on every form, you can set "Behavior entering field" setting to "Select entire field".  (In Access 2007, find that setting from Office Button -> Access Options -> Advanced, then look under the Editing heading of that dialog.  For Access 2003, see [this page](http://malektips.com/access-2003-field-keyboard-stop-select-all.html).)

Not only will that setting be applied to form controls, but also to tables and queries in datasheet view.  If that's not what you want, you can use VBA in your form's module to select the text for only specific controls:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_GotFocus()
    Me.MyTextBox.SelStart = 0
    Me.MyTextBox.SelLength = Len(Me.MyTextBox)
End Sub
```

If you want to do that for multiple controls, you could create a general procedure:

```
Private Sub SelectWholeField()
    Me.ActiveControl.SelStart = 0
    Me.ActiveControl.SelLength = Len(Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub
```

Then call that procedure from the got focus event of an individual control like this:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_GotFocus()
    SelectWholeField
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Field1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 65 Then Me.Field1 = ""
'Or: If Chr(KeyAscii) = "A" Then Me.Field1 = ""
End Sub
```

change the number to the ascii value of whatever key you are wanting to use to clear the field

Comment: I tried the above and every time I press a key it gets erased.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165567%28v=office.10%29.aspx has info on the event. KeyAscii should be the value of the key pressed - try using `msgbox KeyAcii` to see what is being passed to the routine

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Form Level variable

```
Private CanDelete as Boolean
```

When the TextBox receives focus, set CanDelete to True

```
Private Sub txtTest_GotFocus()
  CanDelete = True
End Sub
```

On the KeyPress event, clear the text if CanDelete is True

```
Private Sub txtTest_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  If CanDelete Then
    Me.txtTest = ""
    CanDelete = False
  End If
End Sub
```